# Android, stop view animation once Volley task complete

Tags: android, android-volley

I have this code, I start a rotating animation on an image, immediately after I add a task to a queue with Volley to communicate with the server. However I am having trouble stopping the animation once the request is complete.

I tried passing the view to the function, and stopping the animation in the `onResponse` callback, didnt work though.

```
private void syncDevice(View sync) {
    JSONArray data = db.getData();

    if (data.length() > 0) {
        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        sync.startAnimation(anim);

        //Send data to the server
        sendDataToServer(data);

        showSnackbar(getResources().getString(R.string.device_successfully_synced));
    } else {
        showSnackbar(getResources().getString(R.string.device_already_synced));
    }
}

private void sendDataToServer(JSONArray data) {
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url_base) + getResources().getString(R.string.url_upload_submissions);

    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();

    try {
        js.put("token", token);
        js.put("data", data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,url, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    //Add request to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: Show us how you tried to stop it in onResponse().